# Stacks and queues concept

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

What would be the value of queues Q1, Q2 and stack S after the following algorithm
segment:

1. S = createStack
2. Q1 = createQueue
3. Q2 = createQueue
4. enqueue (Q1, 5)
5. enqueue (Q1, 6)
6. enqueue (Q1, 9)
7. enqueue (Q1, 0)
8. enqueue (Q1, 7)
9. enqueue (Q1, 5)
10. enqueue (Q1, 0)
11. enqueue (Q1, 2)
12. enqueue (Q1, 6)
13. loop (not emptyQueue(Q1))
14. Dequeue(Q1,x)
15. If(x==0)
    1.z=0
    2.loop(not emptyStack(S)
16. popStack(S,y)
17. z=z+y
    3.end loop
    4.enqueue(Q2,z)
18. else
    1.pushStack(S,x)
19. end if
20. end loop

Answer (score 0):

Q1 - Empty

Q2 - (Tail)8,12,20(Head)

S - Empty